# My self-hosted CartoDB map references /api/v1/map -- No route matches

Tags: carto

I'm using a self-hosted install of CartoDB. When I try to publish a visualization using the sample Europe data the visualization page references /api/v1/map which results in a routing error.

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/map"):

I'm serving CartoDB with Apache/Passenger, and all of the other endpoints seem to be working.

I have a ProxyPass setting in Apache to proxy /api/v1/sql requests to the CartoDB SQL API service, but /api/v1/map (and other /api/v1 requests) are passed through to CartoDB itself.

I'm not sure what other info would be useful. Please let me know and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because that route (`/api/v1/map` and everything under it) has to be routed to the tiler application ([Windshaft-cartodb](https://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft-cartodb)) instead of Rails.

Note that if you've got an outdated version of the tiler, it might not have the `/api/v1/map` route yet.
If that happens, you can either

- upgrade Windshaft-cartodb (I think it is mostly compatible with old versions of the Rails app)
- or rewrite `/api/v1/map` to `/tiles/layergroup` on the tiler (you will be missing newer API features, but IIRC those are only used by newer Rails versions).